# About histogram plot in matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a histogram of a list using *density=True* option in the histogram method in matplotlib. The code is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

test=[1,2,3,1,1,3,2,1]
bins=100
plt.hist(test,bins,density=True)
plt.show()
```

I want a probability density plot. For the above example, the probability density of number *1* should be *0.5(4/8)*, of number *2* should be *0.25(2/8)* and that of number *3* should be *0.25(2/8)*. But the code above does not give me the desired plot. The output with the above code is density for number *1* is *2.5*, for numbers *2* and *3* are 1.25.

How can I get a probability density plot either using histogram in matplotlib or another plotting tool in python? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation of [`matplotlib.pyplot.hist`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html), if `density=True`:

> Each bin will display the bin's raw count divided by the total number of counts and the bin width...

Here, the bin width is 0.02 and not 1: `(max(test) - min(test))/bins`

You can also confirm this using `print(plt.hist(test, bins, density=True)[1])`, which gives an array containing bin edges.

That's why, the probability density of 1 is 0.5/0.02 and not 0.5.

To get the desired result, you can try to get counts of unique values in the list and use [`plt.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

test = [1,2,3,1,1,3,2,1]
values, counts = np.unique(test, return_counts=True)

plt.bar(values, counts/len(test))
plt.gca().set_xticks(values)
plt.gca().set_ylim(0, 1)
plt.show()
```

This gives:

[image]